# JDK 9 and the modules graph

Tags: java, java-9

I'm reading a lot of documentations about Jigsaw and I found many examples of **modules graph**.

However I can't find any specification document that explains the meaning or the colors of the arrows/lines that link modules nodes.

The one I found is this: http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/spec/sotms/ written by the guru Mark Reinhold that make this categorization:

- for *explicit dependences*, **dark blue lines**;
- for *implicit dependences*, **light blue lines**;
- for *implied readability*, **dark-blue edges, linked by green edges**

Besides this I watched this video at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V6ycn1-QQV0
presented by another guru, Alan Bateman, that at 23:54 show a module graph with also **dotted lines** connecting nodes...

So, I'm confused about which is the correct shapes to use to connect modules node.

Any idea?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the explanation of specific and non-standardized diagrams (even if programming related) is not generally helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Mark Reinhold talks about it here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y8bpKYDrF5I&t=20m17s.

- **Blue edges** are reexports dependencies
- **Grey edges** are implementation dependencies.

Another way is to compare some module in the documentation (e.g. http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java.corba-summary.html) to its representation in the module graph (in particular the "Requires" and "Indirect Requires" sections).